# Code fails to work when i increase the base numbers to anything over 10 ^ 9

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I am writing an RSA encryption program that calls for two base number that are prime, the larger the better, below is the code from the method

```
def PrimeNumber(self):
    number=random.randint(10**8, 10**9)
    while True:
        prime = self.PrimeTest(number)
        if prime:
            return number
        number+=1
```

in this form the code works perfectly but if I change the random number generator to create a number larger then 10 ^ 9 then the code no longer works when I go to decrypt then message(will explain how I do that below) below are the methods I use to encrypted and decrypted the massages

```
def encryption(self,m):
    c=1
    y =self.publicKey[0]
    d = self.publicKey[1]    
    m=m%y
    for num in range (d):
        c=((c*m)%y)
    return c

def decryption(self,base):
    total = 1 
    power = self.d
    y = self.num
    while power > 0:
        r = power % 2
        if r == 1:
            total = (total * base) % y
        base = (base * base) % y
        power = power// 2
    return total
```

These functions are inverse of each other and again work when the number is 10^9 or smaller. To encrypt the message I break the string apart and change the character to their ascii number and then encrypt that number and do the inverse  for decrypting.This is a quick explanation of RSA if your are unfamiliar with it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

Comment: *"the code no longer works when I go to decrypt then message"* you haven't described how it doesn't work, but I would think that it doesn't terminate. Is that right?

Comment: I am sorry, when I go to decrypt then larger, encrypted number to convert it to its ascii number the number that it returns is wrong and so it can not properly convert I just use ord() and char() to do it.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with `ord()` or `chr()`, but I can say that your exponentiation is greatly inefficient. Look at the three parameter built-in `pow()` function.

Comment: I am converting the inputted string into its ascii values then encrypting that number then sending it. after I decrypted it to its original ascii values and convert it back to a character

Comment: I'd say your code looks fine though your encryption is highly inefficient. As stated, pow will greatly simplify your code. Concerning your problem you might have to post your PrimeTest and/or key generation.

Comment: We tried using pow when we first coded this but it was to inefficient(was taking 15 -20 mins per letter)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you did not use the third parameter of pow (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow) which calculates the modulo and uses this information to drastically reduce computation time.

Answer (score -3):

I will not answer you directly, but have ever tried to count how many bits 10<sup>9</sup> have, and how many bits 10<sup>10</sup> have? If answer to that doesn't lit something in you brain, then sorry - there is no help for you :-)

Ok, let's elaborate on the problem. *(I'm subtracting 2 as bin string starts from '0b')*

```
>>> len(bin(10**9))-2
30
>>> len(bin(10**10))-2
34
```

On any 32-bit operating system standard integer number size is 32-bit (with 1 bit for sign). Numbers of that length are calculated **FAST**. That's because they fit into processor register.

Now, the tricky part lies in how Python handles integers. They're re unlimited in length! They can have 300 bit in length if the number is bit enough. But such long numbers don't fit into CPU registers and they need some trickery to perform any calculation. That trickery is implemented inside the guts of Python interpreter. It's nice thing to have (not always, but that's another story), but they're *EXTREMELY SLOW* in comparison to calculations handled by CPU alone.

In Python 2 (I don't have one installed right now), the type was automatically converted from `int` to `long`. This doesn't take place in Python 3.

If you try play with such big numbers in Python and perform on them operations like multiplication, all this consumes huge amount of time. In effect you cannot effectively implement any algorithm requiring long numbers effectively.

Cryptography is usually handled in dedicated optimized libraries written in C with some assembler optimizations (OpenSSL is an example), where all operation on numbers with even 2048 bits can be handled effectively without much slowdown (any multiplication is usually done by chain of smartly selected bit-shift operations).

I don't think you can implement real-world cryptography algorithm in pure Python. Python is too slow for this.

Comment: I get that there is a shift in the bit size but I don't understand how that effects the code ... don't really talk about this kind of stuff in high school ;(

Comment: if you could leave me a link to what you are referencing though I would be more then happy to try and figure it out on my own